# If a LaTeX compiler is installed on my machine, should typing 'latex' into the command line do anything?

Tags: installing

When I type `latex` into the command line of my windows machine, it says that it is 'not recognised'. Does this mean that no LaTeX compiler is installed on my PC?

Comment: not necessarily, like any command it has to be in your PATH environment variable if the command is to be found just from its name without giving the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably yes, but of course it could also mean that you have one installed, but that is not in your path variable. To check that open a command line and type `echo %PATH%`.

- If you find a directory containing your LaTeX installation then you should try to reinstall, since Windows seems to be unable to find your program although it should be in the path.
- But if not: just add the directory of your LaTeX installation to your path.